# Vlookup value from master data frame and summarize it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a unique data frame having a list of seller names. Below is the sample.

DF_Master_seller

| Seller |
| --- |
| Hari |
| Om |
| Cat |
| Mat |
| John |
| Messi |
| John |
| Ronaldo |
| Shannon |
| Catthy |
| Ray |

I have multiple data frames like -

DF1

| Seller | Vaule | Date | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hari | 2 | Jan-02 | 4.2 |
| Om | 12 | Jan-02 | 3.4 |
| Cat | 0 | Jan-02 | 4.3 |
| Mat | 14 | Jan-02 | 4.3 |

DF2

| Seller | Vaule | Date | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hari | 222 | Oct-02 | 4 |
| Om | 120 | Oct-02 | 3 |
| Cat | 10 | Oct-02 | 2.3 |
| Mat | 143 | Oct-02 | 2.5 |
| John | 30 | Oct-02 | 4.3 |

DF3

| Seller | Vaule | Date | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ray | 22 | Feb-02 | 2.4 |
| Jay | 12 | Feb-02 | 2.5 |
| Sohan | 0 | Feb-02 | 2.2 |
| Mat | 144 | Feb-02 | 5 |
| John | 10 | Feb-02 | 3.4 |

Search each data frame in DF_Master_seller, for each match get the value and calculate the total at last.

Final DF

| Seller | Value_Jan-02 | Value_Feb-02 | Value_Oct-02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hari | 2 |  | 222 |
| Om | 12 |  | 120 |
| Cat | 0 |  | 10 |
| Mat | 14 | 144 | 143 |
| John |  |  | 30 |
| Messi |  |  |  |
| John |  | 10 |  |
| Ronaldo |  |  |  |
| Shannon |  |  |  |
| Catthy |  |  |  |
| Ray |  | 22 |  |
| **Total** | **28** | **176** | **515** |

Note - Column should be ordered by date

Comment: In the final df, why `John` has not `10` in `Value_Feb-02`, can you *double-check*? Seems like a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` to merge `df1`, `df2` and `df3` then reindex by the `Seller` column of master dataframe (`dfM`):

```
# 1st pass: aggregate all dataframes whatever the dates
out = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
         .pivot_table(index='Seller', columns='Date', values='Vaule', 
                      sort=False, fill_value=0)
         .reindex(dfM['Seller'], fill_value=0))

# 2nd pass: reorganize the output
out = (pd.concat([out, out.sum().to_frame('Total').T])
         .sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%b-%y'))
         .add_prefix('Value_').rename_axis(index='Seller', columns=None).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     Seller  Value_Jan-02  Value_Feb-02  Value_Oct-02
0      Hari             2             0           222
1        Om            12             0           120
2       Cat             0             0            10
3       Mat            14           144           143
4      John             0            10            30
5     Messi             0             0             0
6      John             0            10            30
7   Ronaldo             0             0             0
8   Shannon             0             0             0
9    Catthy             0             0             0
10      Ray             0            22             0
11    Total            28           186           555
```

Comment: The column should be in order by date

Comment: Do you control the order of list of dataframes? Here: df1, df3, df2 instead of df1, df2, df3?

Comment: No, the above is the only sample data frame like that I have many data frames.

Answer (score 2):

Same approach as @[*Corralien*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15239951/corralien)'s but with `margins` and sorted columns :

```
out = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
        .pivot_table(index="Seller", values="Vaule", columns="Date",
                     aggfunc="sum", margins=True, margins_name="Total", sort=False)
        .drop(columns="Total").reindex(list(df["Seller"]) + ["Total"])
        .sort_index(key= lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%b-%d"), axis=1)
        .add_prefix("Value").reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output :
​

```
print(out)

     Seller  Value_Jan-02  Value_Feb-02  Value_Oct-02
0      Hari          2.00           NaN        222.00
1        Om         12.00           NaN        120.00
2       Cat          0.00           NaN         10.00
3       Mat         14.00        144.00        143.00
4      John           NaN         10.00         30.00
5     Messi           NaN           NaN           NaN
6      John           NaN         10.00         30.00
7   Ronaldo           NaN           NaN           NaN
8   Shannon           NaN           NaN           NaN
9    Catthy           NaN           NaN           NaN
10      Ray           NaN         22.00           NaN
11    Total         28.00        188.00        525.00
```